# How to measure performance of "App web" for provider hosted app?

Tags: performance, provider-hosted-app

For a provider hosted app in office 365 created with azure service is running slow. Now, how to measure performance of the App web (no the host web)?

Which tool will be used? Please write steps for this?

Answer (score 0):

For monitoring the performance of the app web, you can consider creating a web performance test using Visual Studio. Here is the detail steps:

http://blog.cloudshare.com/2014/02/03/how-to-create-a-web-performance-test-for-sharepoint-2013-using-vs-2013-update-1-part-i/

Also there are other methods you can have a look:

http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/improving-performance-of-sharepoint-sites/part-1-analyse-web-page-performance/#

Comment: This is not the proper answer as I need to measure the "App web". Also don't want to use visual studio for this. Is there any other way than visual studio? Can any senior expert help on this?

Comment: In my opinin, there is no different for monitoring the performance of the app web and the other SharePoint page. You should  find the suitable method in second blog.